# Facebook sharing debugger says The specified 'fb:app:id' property is not a valid app ID

Tags: wordpress, debugging

Hi I am trying to scrape a big thumbnail from a Wordpress URL and I have added the app Id on to a plugin and also added the meta tag on to the header with the following    
`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXXX" />`

but the facebook debugger says that the app id property is not a valid app ID.

Any help will be appreciated!
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this with Yoast SEO. It has excellent documentation on this subject.

I think you should re-check the app ID in your developers account on Facebook. You can see, edit and add apps here:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/